# A team is made up of $11$ regulars and $9$ reserves. Selecting $4$ people from the team, how many distinct groupings can be formed?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

A team is made up of $11$ regulars and $9$ reserves. Selecting $4$ people from the team, how many distinct groupings can be formed?

Comment: Well, your answer is less than one, so it's not correct.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Vinyl_coat_jawa $$\binom{11}{4} \binom{9}{4}$$

Comment: This meaning what?

Comment: That I choose a maximum of four from the 11 regulars and a maximum of 4 from the 9 reserves and then I combine them... I guess

Comment: @Vinyl_coat_jawa it's combination without repetitions

Comment: But then you chose $8$ players, we needed $4$ total.

Comment: @Vinyl_coat_jawa $$\binom{11}{4} \binom{9}{4}4!$$

Comment: I posted some hints in an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm understanding the question completely, so let me explain my interpretation before giving an answer.

You have $11$ regular team members and $9$ reserve team members. We want to count the number of possible groups of 4 members that can be formed through any number of the regular or reserve team members.

In which case, imagine that all $20$ people are grouped together. We don't actually care whether they are regular or reserve team members, just pick $4$ from the total: $\binom{20}{4}$.